# Loading a YAML-file throws an error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I am reading in some YAML-files like this:

```py
data = yaml.safe_load(pathtoyamlfile)
```

When doing so I get the followin error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:value'
```

When checking for the line of the YAML-file which is also given in the error messages I recognized that there is always this key-value-pair: `simple: =`.

Since the YAML-files are autogenerated I am not sure if I can change the files themselves. Is there a way on reading the data of the YAML-files none the less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have hit [this bug](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/89). There is a workaround suggested in the comments.

Given this content in `example.yaml`:

```
example: =
```

This code fails as you've described in your question:

```
import yaml

with open('example.yaml') as fd:
  data = yaml.safe_load(fd)
print(data)
```

But this works:

```
import yaml

yaml.SafeLoader.yaml_implicit_resolvers.pop('=')
with open('example.yaml') as fd:
  data = yaml.safe_load(fd)
print(data)
```

And outputs:

```
{'example': '='}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the input, you might be able to upgrade the library that you use:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
example: =
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for key, value in data.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

which gives:

```
example: =
```

Please be aware that `ruamel.yaml` still has this bug in its safe mode loading ( `YAML(typ='safe')` ).